# Environment variables don't work

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I can't get any environment variables to work besides Java. Here's a picture to show what I mean:

[image]

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables don't work like that.

To substitute the value of an environment variable, use `%VariableName%`.
Thus, you can write `%CACHE%.

`java` is working because `java.exe` is already in the system `%PATH%`.